openpyxl workbook.save(file_path) corrupting .xlsx file
I am trying to write a python file to do some .xlsx file editing.  I am having some success with that.  When saving and closing the .xlsx file I am getting errors when opening the saved file using Excel. The .py file is a mess of stuff so I simplified the file to be simply open, save, close using openpxyl and I still get the same error.  Running on Windows 10 machine. Excel is from 2007.  I am thinking that maybe the 2007 version of excel is the problem.  I thought I read somewhere that openpyxl was for Excel 2010.
Python code is
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
import datetime
import time
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl.styles import Font



file_path = "error test.xlsx"
workbook = load_workbook(filename=file_path)
worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]

# Save the file
workbook.save(file_path)


# Finally, close the Excel file
# via the close() method.
workbook.close()


Excel error on opening file
Excel recovery message
XML error file:
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<logFileName>error441200_02.xml</logFileName>
<summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\C Drive Documents\Pete Home\Python Excel\error test.xlsx'</summary>
<removedParts summary="Following is a list of removed parts:">
<removedPart>Removed Part: /xl/comments/comment1.xml part with XML error. (Comments) Load error. Line 1, column 203.</removedPart>
<removedPart>Removed Part: /xl/comments/comment2.xml part with XML error. (Comments) Load error. Line 1, column 203.</removedPart>
</removedParts>
</recoveryLog>

I tried reading about xml style information as the error .xml file message talks about but I could not figure out how to associate style information during the workbook.save command.  I just read this about Office Open XML file formats:
*
The formats were developed by Microsoft and first appeared in Microsoft Office 2007. So maybe my 2007 version of Excel should be OK.*
I did more reading and learned that it is likely because my .xlsx file has plots in several of the worksheets that I am editing.  I read several posts regarding how to fix that but they did not seem to deal with charts/plots within the worksheet that I need to edit.  I did create a dummy .xlsx file with no graphics and the code above of open/save/close did not corrupt the file
I also did not understand one post that talks about using powershell to do the read/save
So if there are any new ways of dealing with graphics within an .xlsx worksheet please share them
Here is an update after reading your comments/questions:
Thanks for your help and comments.  I'll try to answer your questions first and then tell you what I have been doing.  I do not believe there is anything in column 203 in any worksheets (there are 6) in the original file so I have to assume the save process is putting something there.  If I save the file after it gets repaired and open it again it does NOT have the same error.  Because Excel corrects the file when it is opened I cannot see what the comments error in line 1, 203 looks like.  What I have done so far is identified the worksheet that is causing the problem.  There are 2 identical worksheets that cause the 2 problems reported in the .html file. So I copied the useful part of that worksheet and created a new file and pasted that content into it and ran the simple open/save/close .py file on it and it produces the error when opening up the processesed .xls file.  I am trying to figure out how to upload the .xlsx test file for you to look at.  How do I upload the file?

What is in column 203.  It happens with Excel that workbooks do get corrupted and there isn't much you can do.  Often the error is in the binary data that cannot be seen on the worksheet.  if you save the file after it is repaired do you still get the error?

According to the Repairs to message there are problems with comments. So the problem is with the content of your error test.xlsx, especially with cell comments. Can you upload that file (the version before open/saved via openpyxl) somewhere? Or unzip the error test.xlsx and have a look into /xl/comments/comment1.xml. What do you find there on line 1 around column 203? Should be something like <text><t>The text of the comment</t></text>. And in "The text of the comment" is the problematic part.

I would need a file to say more about the comments. The comments XML files aren't actually necessary because Excel stores the same data in three different places. Speculating about other possible problems is a waste of time.

I think I uploaded the file to here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oQeNiHYVAPYMvYa66mTRyMWCLnfPRxNF/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102427747426682067780&rtpof=true&sd=true

I found the problem in the test file - there are comments in several cells in col F that cause the problem.  I created a new test.xlsx file with nothing in it but a comment in any cell and did open/save/close.py and it created the same error when opening the processed test file.  So the problem is with the workbook.save call.  Something for someone at openpyxl to look at someday.  Thanks for your help
